# Get value for Style from property of the instance to be styled

Tags: c#, xaml

I would like to create elements during runtime and add a style to them.

Given the following Xaml, I would like to bind the value for the property `Center` to the actual values of a styled object (see main method). I tried different Binding notations but without success (propably because I am still new to xaml). I also tried to just change the `Center` on the instance but the instance is frozen and cannot be changed.

```
<Window x:Name="window" x:Class="CirclePing.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="AlertBubble" TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Data">
                <Setter.Value>

                    <!-- how can I bind Center to the Tag property of a 'styled' instance? -->
                    <EllipseGeometry x:Name="circle"
                                Center="200,200" 
                                RadiusX="100" 
                                RadiusY="100">
                    </EllipseGeometry>

                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Fill">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <RadialGradientBrush>
                        <GradientStop Color="Black"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#2F5CB2"/>
                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="OpacityMask">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <RadialGradientBrush>
                        <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="0.5"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

My `Main` method:

```
    InitializeComponent();

    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        var path = new Path();

        int positionX = r.Next(1400);
        int positionY = r.Next(800);
        path.Tag = new Point(positionX, positionY);

        path.Style = (Style)this.Resources["AlertBubble"]; 
     }
```

Now I would like the following to be true: `(EllipseGeometry)path.Data).Center.Y == positionY`. What binding expression should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind Center using **`RelativeSource`** markup extension and finding parent Path instance object like this:

```
<EllipseGeometry x:Name="circle"
                 Center="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                       Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Path}}" 
                 RadiusX="100" 
                 RadiusY="100"/>
```

Comment: I now get the error: `System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Shapes.Path', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=Tag; DataItem=null; target element is 'EllipseGeometry' (HashCode=61693801); target property is 'Center' (type 'Point')`

Comment: You might be getting this error logged in your output window. But have you tried running the program and see if it works because it is working completely fine at my end.

Comment: You are right. I had to add the path to the canvas first. Thanks!